# SearchKit Actions button disabled / Authorization failed

Tags: drupal, search, searchkit, search-builder, drupal-7

Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.69.2, PHP 7.4, Smarty 2.

Have been trying to set some 2K+ emails on hold via the beautiful SearchKit, however the "Actions" button does not summon any actions on click - had to  change the "#bootstrap-theme .dropdown-menu" display:none property to see the thing and do the job.

There is possible related **"Authorization failed"** message in civi logs, however all permissions are set properly, moreover, the same custom search was working fine a few months ago.

```
[error] 
 $Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
"message" => "Authorization failed"
"code" => null
"exception" => Civi\API\Exception\UnauthorizedException {#2138
-errorData: array:1 [
  "error_code" => "unauthorized"
]
#cause: null
-_trace: null
#message: "Authorization failed"
#code: 0
#file: "/srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php"
#line: 230
trace: {
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php:230 {
    Civi\API\Kernel->authorize($apiProvider, $apiRequest)
    › if (!$event->isAuthorized()) {
    ›   throw new \Civi\API\Exception\UnauthorizedException("Authorization failed");
    › }
  }
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php:147 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php:256 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/ext/search_kit/Civi/Search/Admin.php:138 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/ext/search_kit/Civi/Search/Admin.php:36 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/Civi/Angular/AngularLoader.php:150 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources/CollectionTrait.php:394 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php:142 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php:157 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:156 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/includes/common.inc:6036 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/includes/common.inc:2820 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/includes/common.inc:2708 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/includes/common.inc:751 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/DrupalBase.php:251 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php:63 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:242 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:472 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/includes/menu.inc:527 { …}
  /srv/www//public_html/index.php:21 { …}
}
```

}
]

[image]